# Intellij-IDEA plugin development: How do I test opening a different file in a new tab?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm reading this documentation: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Testing+IntelliJ+IDEA+Plugins

One thing I can't figure out how to do with a `CodeInsightTestFixture` is a test case like this:

1. create a file with "a" as content and open it
2. create a file with "b" as content and open it
3. open the first file
4. assert that the current document content is "a"

---

I tried this but it fails:

```
//myFixture is a com.intellij.testFramework.fixtures.CodeInsightTestFixture
PsiFile psiFile = myFixture.configureByText(PlainTextFileType.INSTANCE, "a");
myFixture.configureByText(PlainTextFileType.INSTANCE, "b");
myFixture.openFileInEditor(psiFile.getVirtualFile());
myFixture.checkResult("a");
```

The error is:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: TEXT 
Expected :a
Actual   :b
```

---

I thought I had the answer:

> This passed when I tried it:
>
> ```
> PsiFile psiFile = myFixture.configureByText("a.txt", "a");
> myFixture.configureByText("b.txt", "b");
> myFixture.openFileInEditor(psiFile.getVirtualFile());
> myFixture.checkResult("a");
> ```
>
> Still not sure why the original doesn't though.  Perhaps the original only replaces the current file?

Turns out this is not the answer.  I think there's one `Editor` per test fixture.  All I've done in this test is change the content of the editor to be different.  It's not the same as "viewing a new tab".  I've since learned that "each tab has its own editor" so this original question doesn't make much sense.  What I'm really trying to ask is "Intellij-IDEA plugin development: How do I test opening a different file in a new tab?"

Answer (score 0):

"Opening a file in a new tab" is part of IntelliJ IDEA's core functionality; I don't see why you would need to test this as part of your plugin tests. Also, it's correct that the test fixture has only one editor.

If your tests generate or modify multiple files, you can use the three-parameter overload of CodeInsightTestFixture.checkResultByFile() to check that each file has the expected contents.

Comment: I care because of this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-523 How do I know if the correct editor is active when the `CodeInsightTestFixture` only has one?